# Android Studio 4.1: XML Resource ID auto Fetching issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

I have recently updated my Android studio along with SDK and Gradle. My current version is given below-

Android Studio version: 4.1

Android Gradle Plugin Version: 4.1.0

Gradle Version: 6.5

After the update, I am unable to get the XML resource ID from class files such as Activity, Fragment, etc. I am getting an error "Unresolved reference" error while accessing the ID from the Activity onCreate method.

Update: I think the findViewById reappears in Android Studio 4.1. We can only access the XML resource ID via findViewById.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add 'kotlin-android-extensions' in build.gradle (Module: ~.app)

(Before) -------------------------------------

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}
```

(After) -------------------------------------

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

2. Press "Sync Now" on Upper Right
   [image]
3. Press "Ok, apply suggestion!" on Upper Right

Comment: From the Android Studio 4.2, you would be recommended to use [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding), though.

Answer (score 0):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

Add the `kotlin-android-extensions` plugin in your app level gradle module.